# How can I filter out numbers from this letter-number pairs?

Tags: python

I have scraped this out of a webserver using beautiful soup

```
C,9
C,9
C,9
H,8
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,7
H,5
H,2
C,0
C,7
C,8
C,4
C,1
C,7
C,6
C,6
C,0
C,2
C,1
E,2
E,4
E,1
C,5
C,9
C,9
C,9
C,7
C,7
H,5
H,4
H,8
H,9
H,9
H,7
H,6
H,5
C,7
C,9
C,9
C,9
C,8
C,6
C,4
C,1
C,1
C,0
E,2
E,4
E,1
E,3
E,7
C,6
C,9
C,9
C,9
C,5
E,7
E,8
E,8
E,6
E,4
C,8
C,9
C,9
C,9
C,9
H,6
H,7
H,7
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,9
H,6
H,3
H,2
C,9
```

That how its printed out, I haven't edited it from the webserver.

I want to remove the number, so all that is left is the letter. 
How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a very well-defined question. For example, do you want the result to be a string of comma-separated letters, or do you want an actual Python list? (Or something else)

Comment: You do know you can edit the question to make it clear what you're asking, right? That will help the downvotes and close votes go away, but more importantly, it will greatly improve the quality of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\d', '', s) # or re.sub(r',\d', '', s) to remove the commas, too
```

assuming `s` is the string you have.

Comment: It's a Beautiful soup object how can I change it too a string?

Comment: @miik I'm guessing `str(obj)` should return a string.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way is to copy the chars into an array and test whether each char is equal to 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. After removing it, you can output the array or do whatever you want.